# Network tape devices for backing up from server 2012 virtual machine

Tags: networking, tape, hyper-v-server-2012

Are there any network attached tape devices available to allow us to get data from a server 2012 R2 VM on hyper-V backed-up onto tape?

First problem is that server 2012 doesn't support backup to tape, but that can be solved with a 3rd party tape backup solution.

Second problem is how to get the virtual machine, server 2012 R2, to somehow communicate with the tape drive, hyper-V does not support USB passthrough.

How is everyone else getting their data written to tape in the hyper-v world?

Comment: You have a USB tape drive? **Shudder**. The vast majority of professional-grade tape devices are either SCSI or SAS based.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to go to tape vs disc?  Most tape devices are direct attached as @EEAA stated and getting that to pass through from the host to the guest, at least last I checked, isn't supported.  If you want to backup to tape you may need a third party tool such as [Veeam](http://www.veeam.com/) that supports backups to tape and can run on a separate machine.  We're using Veeam for replication so we're not using the tape feature but it does support archive/backups to tape devices.

Comment: Simple.  By a network-based tape solution.  People sell devices you attach to your network.  These network appliances often include a disk, so basically you are going from disk to disk to tape.

Comment: "network-based tape solution", well thats what I have been looking for but can't seem to find anything suitable for the smaller end of the market.

Comment: @EEAA how would having a SCSI or SAS based device help, would we not still have the same problems getting the windows VM to write to tape?  If it is as simple as buying a SAS or SCSI drive then we can do that.